# Syntax error with simple button.grid(row=1, column=0) code - tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, grid-layout

Im getting a syntax error, if i take out the 'Button' code it works.

I think it is to do with the grid function, but im not sure how to fix it.

```
from tkinter import *

app=Tk()
app.title("Framing Demo")

Label(app, text="Why not...", bg="blue", font="none 12 bold").grid(row=0,     
column=0)
Label(app, text="Start now?", bg="pink", font="arial 10 
italic").grid(row=1, column=1)
Button(app, text"Register", fg="orange").grid(row=1, column=0)

app.mainloop()
```

The 'invalid syntax' message appears, and there is no message in IDLE, and the program does not start.

Comment: Typo: You're missing the `=` in `text="Register"`

Comment: `text="Register"`. Not `text"Register`

Comment: Did you read the traceback error message?

Comment: oh wow, can't believe i missed that, thought it was something more complex, thank you! @Barmar

Comment: there wasnt one unfortunately @wjandrea

Comment: thanks! @roganjosh

Comment: @wjandrea Syntax errors don't generate tracebacks, since they happen when the script is being compiled, not when it's running.

Comment: @Barmar i never mentioned a traceback?

Comment: Sorry, wrong attribution.

Comment: @Barmar Right, thanks! I meant the detailed error message that shows where the syntax error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

You missed out an equals sign inside the Button object when declaring the variables

It should be

```
 text = "Register"
```

whereas it is

```
 text"Register"
```

Comment: Don't bother answering trivial typo problems like this, they should just be closed with a comment.

Comment: I would have left a comment but I still don't have enough rep to do so. I'll keep in mind for the future though!

Comment: There was already a comment, you didn't need to leave one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a '=' sign in this line

```
Button(app, text"Register", fg="orange").grid(row=1, column=0)
```

Replace it with this

```
Button(app, text="Register", fg="orange").grid(row=1, column=0)
```

Comment: Don't bother answering trivial typo problems, they should just be closed with a comment.